# MAC spoofing preventing connection

Tags: linux, mac-address, mac-spoofing

I'm attempting MAC spoofing on a network I own. I'm connecting to a NETGEAR WNDR4300 wireless router from an Ubuntu Linux machine. The network uses WPA2-PSK [AES] security.

Connecting to the network with an un-spoofed MAC works fine. I can bring my network interface down with

```
sudo ip link set dev wlan1 down
```

and then spoof my MAC with either

```
sudo macchanger -e wlan1
```

or manually with

```
sudo ip link set dev wlan1 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

(picking some address). Both techniques work. When I bring the interface up with

```
sudo ip link set dev wlan1 up
```

it attempts to reconnect to the network, then prompts me for the password. I enter the correct password, but it fails to connect. I've tried this numerous times, with various MACs (random, same vendor, etc.), without success.

What's going wrong, or how can I diagnose the issue?

Comment: Can you try restarting your router as well?

Comment: @KerimOguzcanYenidunya - I'd really rather not; the router is working perfectly and handles every connection request from every device. I suspect this may be an Ubuntu bug as 
AdnanG suggests, but am still investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the solution to your problem in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/243818/change-mac-address-of-a-wireless-network-adapter) answer on superuser:

Some more information on a big related to your issue [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/787192).

Comment: Please don't post an answer with just a link. Include the relevant content from the link. For more tips on writing answers, read [answer].

Answer (score 1):

If the above answer doesn't help, if I remember correctly this router has the ability to perform MAC address filtering (?) you may want to check that this is either turned off, or compatible with the MAC address you are choosing.